# Structured transfer function estimation in MATLAB?

Tags: optimization, matlab, control-theory, system-identification

I have some input-output data for a dynamical system (input = stimulus, output = observation). Assuming that this system is linear time-invariant, I am trying to estimate a transfer function $H(s)$ of this system in MATLAB. I found the function `tfest` in the System Identification Toolbox. It allows you to define the number of poles, the number of zeros, and even some delay.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to force the transfer function to have a certain structure. For example, 
$$H(s) = H_1(s) + \alpha \, e^{-\tau s} \, H_2(s).$$

Is there a way to estimate this structured transfer function in Matlab?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe that MATLAB does not support such structure if you would construct such transfer function manually, so I doubt it would be able to fit it as well. However you might be able to approximate this by using a higher order transfer function, since delays can be approximated with for example Padé approximations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know if that is, what you are asking for.

I did the following

```
alpha = 1;
tau = 1;
s = tf('s');
H1 = 1/(s+2)^2; % arbitrary transfer function 
H2 = s/(s+1)^3; % arbitrary transfer function
H = H1 + alpha * exp(-tau*s) * H2
```

By this method, you will obtain the state-space model which you can try to fit.

You can also check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530755/estimate-a-transfer-function-from-data/2531239#2531239).